# Center of convex figure

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, convex-geometry

Let us denote by $|F-G|_H$ the [Hausdorff distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_distance) between compact sets $F$ and $G$ in the plane.

> Is it possible to choose a point $p_F\in F$ in any non-empty compact convex figure $F\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ such that
> $$|p_F-p_G|\leqslant |F-G|_H?$$

**Comments**

- The barycentre [does not work](https://mathoverflow.net/q/96254).
- The center of minimal ball containing the figure does not work. Look at the two triangles shown below (this example was suggested by [Saúl RM](https://mathoverflow.net/users/172802/sa%C3%BAl-rm)).

  [image]
- Now we see that there is no such choice (thanks to Saúl RM and Fedja). Let me mention that it also implies that there is no short retraction $\mathrm{Haus}\,\mathbb{R^2}\to \mathbb{R^2}$. Here $\mathrm{Haus}\,\mathbb{R^2}$ denotes the set of all nonempty compact sets in the plane equipped with Hausdorff metric and $\mathbb{R^2}$ is considered as a subspace of $\mathrm{Haus}\,\mathbb{R^2}$ via the distance-preserving embedding that sens a point $x$ to the one-point set $\{x\}$.
- It was proved that the best choice is the so-called *Steiner center* $s_F$ --- the  center of mass of curvature of $\partial F$. Namely, we have
  $$|s_F-s_G|\leqslant \tfrac4\pi\cdot|F-G|_H.$$
  This statement (plus the higher-dimensional version) was proved by E. D. Positzelskii in his "Lipschitz mappings..." (1971); it was rediscovered by Krzysztof Przesławski and David Yost in their "Continuity properties of selectors..." (1989) and it is a simple corollary of the results of Denis Rutovitz (1965) and Igor Daugavet (1968). It also appear as Proposition 2.21 in "Geometric nonlinear functional analysis. Vol. 1" by Yoav Benyamini and Joram Lindenstrauss.

Comment: I guess that take the gravity center works, but I am unable to check it. The gravity center of a non-empty compact convex set is $p_F = \lambda_F(F)^{-1} \int_F xd\lambda_F(x)$ where $\lambda_F$ is the Lebesgue measure on the affine space generated by $F$.

Comment: One candidate for which I didn't find an obvious counterexample: the barycenter of the boundary of the convex set (we can parametrize the boundary by unit length and then find the barycenter of that). In segments it is just the middle point

Comment: @SaúlRM did you thaut about baryceter of curvature? (In other words  baryceter of vertices of polygon with weights proportional to their external angles.)

Comment: @SaúlRM BTW it seems that for line segments only, one can choose their midpoints, but I cannot verify it.

Comment: No, I hadn't thought of the barycenter of curvature. The pity is that it doesn't seem easy to check if any of these barycenters work. About the line segments, I think of their boundary as traversing the segment and then traversing it in the opposite direction, so under that definition the middle point is still the barycenter of the boundary

Comment: @SaúlRM still, suppose two line segment are $\varepsilon$-close --- why their midpoints are  $\varepsilon$-close?

Comment: @AntonPetrunin If $[a,b]$ and $[c,d]$ are $t$-close, then $a-c, b-d\le t$, so $\frac{a+b}2-\frac{c+d}2\le t$ and we can exchange the intervals to get the other bound.

Comment: @fedja, this is 1-dimensional case, but I see it now --- it is true since it is true for any projection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There does not exist any function $p:F\mapsto p_F$ as in the question, to prove it by contradiction suppose such a function $p$ exists. In the following let $k+A=\{k+a;a\in A\}$ for any $k\in\mathbb{R}^2$, $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2$

To see why, consider the triangle $T_0$ with vertices $(-1,0),(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$. Let $r:(x,y)\mapsto(x,-y)$ be the reflection respect to the $x$ axis.

Now consider for each natural $n$ the triangle $T_n=r^n(T_0+10(n,0))$, and let $p_{T_n}=(x_n,y_n)$. Note that $d_H(T_n,T_{n+1})=10$, so $\sqrt{(x_{n+1}-x_n)^2+(y_{n+1}-y_n)^2}=d(p_{T_n},p_{T_{n+1}})\leq 10$. This, of course, implies that $x_{n+1}-x_n\leq10$. Moreover, $(y_{n+1}-y_n)^2=(|y_{n+1}|+|y_n|)^2$, since $y_n$ and $y_{n+1}$ have opposite signs.

This will allow us to deduce by contradiction that $y_n\to 0$: if not, we would have some $\varepsilon>0$ and infinitely many $n$ such that $|y_n|>\varepsilon$, so $x_{n+1}-x_n<\sqrt{100-\varepsilon^2}$. This implies that for big enough $n$, we will have $x_n-x_0<10n-2$, which is impossible since $10n-2=d(T_n,T_0)$.

Similarly, let $S_0$ be the triangle with vertices $(-1,1),(1,1)$ and $(0,0)$, let $s$ be the reflection around the line $y=1$ and let $S_n=s^n(S_0+10(n,0))$. Then letting $p_{S_n}=(z_n,w_n)$, we can prove that $w_n\to 1$ as before. So for big enough even $n$ we have $d_H(T_n,S_n)=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ and $d(p_n,q_n)\geq0.9$, the contradiction we were looking for.

Comment: Yep, you proof is simpler. The underlying idea is essentially the same but you use one direction only, which makes both the argument and its quantification fairly simple. Congratulations! Now let's try to tighten the bounds :-)

Comment: You should publish it.

Comment: Actually your original argument works too. If we have an $L$-Lipschitz $p$, then we can average $p(v+K)-v$ over big disks and take a limit to get a version commuting with translations and then $R^{-1}p(RK)$ over rotations $R$ to get it commuting with rotations too, without changing $L$. This observation should allow to get fairly good bounds, especially from below. I hope I didn't miss anything.

Comment: More precisely, since the isometry invariant version must assign to an equilateral triangle its center, we can place two such triangles in the "hourglass" configuration and get the lower bound $L\ge 2/\sqrt 3$ immediately.

Comment: @fedja Wow, that seems like it's going to work. I will think about it later in detail (and your proof too, I am just studying ultrafilters so it will be a good exercise)

Comment: @AntonPetrunin I'm not sure how publishing works, I am a first year PhD student right now. Also, fedja published a complete proof a few minutes before me

Comment: I think that the central idea is yours + you may try to cooperate with Fedja (he knows how to publish).

Comment: (I would write it as elementary as possible and send it to Math Monthly or Math Intelligencer)

Comment: Thanks for the information! I have left my email in my profile in case @fedja is interested in collaborating.

Comment: @SaúlRM It could be a nice project and it may make a good Monthly article, but then (IMHO) it would make sense to try to figure out the optimal Lipschitz constant before sending anything to a journal. Journal publishing process is easy, BTW: you type the article in TeX, proofread it 5 times, go to the journal webpage and follow the instructions for uploading files. With some of them (Monthly included) you are also strongly encouraged to use their TeX header (downloadable from the journal webpage) to have the journal format from the start. No rocket science. I'll send you an e-mail later. :-).

Comment: @AntonPetrunin Now, once the problem is solved (at least in the originally posted formulation) the question "What led you to asking it?" becomes legitimate (especially if you suggest that SaulRM makes a formal publication). So what's the underlying story here (if there is one)?

Comment: @fedja I agree, it would make sense finding the constant or some good upper/lower bounds before sending anything

Comment: In an answer to a post linked in the question (https://mathoverflow.net/questions/120240/), Günter Rote seems to claim "The best Lipschitz constant (for the Hausdorff distance) is achieved by the so-called Steiner point". Is that a different constant than what is discussed here?

Comment: In Oliver Klein's [thesis](https://refubium.fu-berlin.de/bitstream/handle/fub188/12978/Dissertation_OliverKlein.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y) it claims that for centers invariant by translations, the constant $\frac{4}{\pi}$ is the minimal one, and it is satisfied by the Steiner center. And taking into account the comment above by Fedja it shoud indeed be the same constant for centers that are not necessarily invariant by translation. Btw I think the Steiner point is the one we mentioned in the comments to [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/432793/172802)

Comment: Also, @fedja it seems like this topic has been well studied, I don't think there is no need to contact me anymore, but thanks anyways :) (I will delete this message later if I remember)

Comment: @YoavKallus thanks (evidently I did not read this answer to the end).

Comment: @SaúlRM no, this center is only $C^{\frac12}$ continuous.

Comment: @AntonPetrunin maybe you are referring to the center from the answer, and not the one we mentioned in the comments? I would have referenced the comment but I don't know if that is possible

Comment: @fedja I was thinking about metric spaces $X$ that admit a short retraction $\mathrm{Haus}\,X\to X$; here $\mathrm{Haus}\,X$  denotes the set of all nonempty compact sets of $X$ equipped with Hausdorff metric. Evidently injective spaces and descrete spaces are among the examples. I am not sure, maybe all length spaces with this property are injective.

Answer (score 2):

OK, here is why $Lip1$ is impossible.
Suppose we have such choice.
Then consider all $K$ whose minimal containing box is a unit square.
Let $[x(K),x(K)+1]\times[y(K),y(K)+1]$ be the minimal containing box of $K$. Let $e=(1,0)$. Note that if $L$ is another such domain, then for fixed $t$ and $T\to+\infty$, we have $d_H(te+K,Te+L)=(T-t)+x(L)-x(K)+o(1)$ (the fixed vertical shift becomes of no importance).
Thus, we conclude that if $p(te+K).x-x(te+K)=w$, then $p(Te+L).x-x(Te+L)\le w+o(1)$ as $T\to\infty$, whence the difference $p(Te+K).x-x(Te+K)$ has a (usual) limit $w_x$ independent of $K$ as $T\to+\infty$.
Now if we define
$$
p_T(K)=p(Te+K)-Te
$$
and put $p_1(K)=\lim_T p_T(K)$ where the limit is taken with respect to some ultrafilter containing the usual filter of rays going to $+\infty$, we shall get a choice whose $x$-coordinate is $x(K)+w_x$ for every $K$ in our class and that choice still is $Lip1$. Now we can run the same construction in the $y$-direction and conclude that we can make a $Lip1$ choice $p_2$ such that $p(K).y=y(K)+w_y$ as well. But then for this class of domains, choosing the box center works as well. However if we take $K=conv((-1,0),(0,-1),(0,0))$ and $L=-K$ and observe that $d_H(K,L)=1$ but the box shift is of length $\sqrt2$.

Remarks:

1. The ultrafilter is not really needed but it makes the proof very transparent, so I decided to use it. Those who dislike AC are welcome to recast it as an argument with classical limits only (or, better, without limits at all using the pigeonhole principle instead) as an exercise.
2. While this argument shows that the minimal possible Lipschitz constant is strictly greater than $1$ (if we could get it arbitrarily close to $1$, we could get $1$ as well by taking the limit along, erm, some ultrafilter on positive integers containing the standard filter for the usual limit), it does not provide any explicit lower bound. So finding a reasonable lower bound $1+\delta$ for the Lipschits constant remains an open problem (*some* quantification is actually possible even using just finitely many shifts of the last two triangles, but I would rather not write down the ridiculously small $\delta$ it yields).
3. I hope that is all correct, but check everything carefully because it is quite late here now and I'm not at my best today :-)

Comment: What does $p(te+K).x$ mean?

Comment: @SaúlRM it is $x$-coordinate.

Answer (score 0):

Almost complete proof (the final argument still needs to be formalized).

We work in any Euclidean space $E$.

Informally, I take $p_F$ equal to the center of the closed ball with minimum radius containing $F$ (existence and uniqueness are shown below).

For $\delta \ge 0$, call $B_\delta$ the closed ball with radius $\delta$ centered at $0$.

By definition, given two non-empty compact sets $F$ and $G$, the Hausdorff distance  $|F-G|_H$ is the least $\delta$ such that $F \subset G + B_\delta$ and $G \subset F + B_\delta$.

For every non-empty compact convex set $F$, and every $x \in E$, set $f_F(x) = \sup\{d(x,y) : y \in F\}$. Observe that for each $r \ge 0$, $f_F(x) \le r$ if and only if $F \subset \overline{B}(x,r)$.

The function $f_F$ is $1$-Lipschitz hence continuous. Its infimum on $F$ is achieved (by compactness) at only one point (by convexity). Indeed, if $F$ is contained in two closed ball with same radius with centers $x_1 \ne x_2$, it is contained in some ball centered at $(x_1+x_2)/2$ with smaller radius. Hence $$r_F := \min_{x \in F} f_F(x) \text{ and } p_F := \arg\min_{x \in F} f_F(x)$$
are well-defined.

Now consider another non-empty compact convex set $G$, and set $\delta = |F-G|_H$. Then
$$G \subset F+B_\delta \subset \overline{B}(p_F,r_F) + B_\delta = \overline{B}(p_F,r_F+\delta),$$
so $$r_G \le f_G(p_F) \le r_F+\delta.$$
Of course, we can reverse the roles of $F$ and $G$. By symmetry, we may and we do assume that $r_G \ge r_F$. One has
$$G \subset \overline{B}(p_G,r_G) \cap \overline{B}(p_F,r_F+\delta).$$
(To be formalized, looks clear on a picture) I claim that $\overline{B}(p_G,r_G) \subset \overline{B}(p_F,r_F+\delta)$, so $|p_F-p_G| \le r_F+\delta-r_G \le \delta$. Otherwise, the intersection of these two balls would be contained in some ball with center in $G$ (starting from $p_G$, move a bit the center in the direction of $p_F$) and radius $<r_G$, and this would contradict the definition of $r_G$.

Comment: Please see the example I added to the question.

Comment: Nice counter-examples. So the last argument is false, I suppose that there is still a Lipschitz constant, greater than 1. It would have been nice to give these negative answers in the question, to avoid wrong reflexions. Do you have other natural candidates which fail?

Comment: Another candidate for $p_F$: the barycenter of the (convex) subset of all points which maximize the distance to $F^c$?

Comment: No, the map is only $C^{\frac12}$-continuous.

Comment: I would check baryceter with of vertices of polygon with weights proportional to their external angles.

Comment: *Some* Lipschitz constant is trivial. We have such point on the line (the center of the interval). Now just project to two coordinate axis and use the centers of projections for the coordinates of $p$, which gives you Lipschitz constant $\sqrt 2$ immediately.

Comment: Other way to obtain Lipschitz constant $\sqrt{2}$ is to fix any unitary vector $v$ and take as center $p_{F,v}$ of $F$ the center of the minimum rectangle parallel to $v$ that contains $F$. Maybe if we define a center $p_F$ to be the average over $v\in\mathbb{S}^1$ of $p_{F,v}$ the resulting center has Lipschitz constant $<\sqrt{2}$? Minimizing the Lipschitz constant seems an interesting question

Comment: @SaúlRM It is exactly the same construction as mine only I was too lazy to rotate the axes in my comment, but the thought of considering the average over axis rotations crossed my mind too though I decided to spend some time on trying to prove that you cannot achieve $1$ first, which I'm doing now :-)

Comment: Cool. I was pretty sure that was going to work but I wasn't able to prove it, and indeed that center (and I think every other construction that has been mentioned until now) would be invariant by isometries so as I explain in my answer it cannot work

Comment: @SaúlRM The idea I'm trying to pursue now is to figure out all $p$ we can use on the line with $1+\delta$ (it seems that you cannot deviate too much from some fixed convex combination of endpoints though the combination may depend on the line direction) and then to place various intervals around $K$ to run into trouble.

Comment: I don't understand that comment very well, but if you find something interesting with that construction (like a Lipschitz constant less than $\sqrt{2}$) I would be interested :) I tried but I couldn't deduce anything relevant about that center

Comment: @SaúlRM OK, I found "something interesting" and even posted it as an answer, but the problem about the least Lipschitz constant is still far from the full resolution :-)

Comment: Cool, I will read the proof now. I was already finishing one myself so I also left it posted