# Short selection in the space of subsets

Tags: mg.metric-geometry

Given a metric space $X$, denote by $\mathrm{Haus}\,X$ the space of all compact subsets in $X$ equipped with Hausdorff metric.
Further $X$ will be identified with a subset of $\mathrm{Haus}\,X$ --- a point $x\in X$ corresponds to the one-point set $\{x\}\subset X$.

A metric space $X$ will be called ***nice*** if there is a short (= 1-lipschitz) retract $\mathrm{Haus}\,X\to X$.
In other words, if for any compact set $A\subset X$ there is a point $p_A\in X$ such that $p_{\{x\}}=x$ and
$$|p_A-p_B|_X\leqslant |A-B|_{\mathrm{Haus}\,X}.$$
(Note that we do *not* assume that $p_A\in A$.)

For example, any [injective space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_metric_space) is nice. Also, discrete spaces (all distances = 1) are nice. On the other hand, [Euclidean plane is not nice](https://mathoverflow.net/q/432694/).

> Is there an example of a nice compact geodesic space which is not injective?

Comment: The Lipschitz niceness condition can also be written as: for any $X,Y$, there are $x\in X,\,y\in Y$ with $d(x,y)\ge d(f(X),f(Y))$ and $d(x,y)$ equal to either $d(x,Y)$ or $d(X,y)$.

Comment: @MattF. No, I do *not* assume $r(A)\in A$.  $r(A)$ might be any point such that $r(\{x\})=x$ and $|r(A)-r(B)|\leqslant|A-B|_H$.

Comment: This is just another way of saying that the Hausdorff distance between $X$ and $Y$ is greater than that between $f(X)$ and $f(Y)$ — so the $x\in X,y\in Y$ there just comes from the definition of Hausdorff distance. Without that clause the condition I wrote would be trivial; as it stands it is equivalent to the condition in the post.

Comment: If $(X,d)$ is a metric space and $\epsilon \in (0,1)$, then $(X, d^\epsilon)$ is also a metric space (called a ``snowflake'' of $(X,d)$). It seems to me that if the former space is nice, then so is the latter, trivially. The snowflake will not be injective. For a concrete example, take $X=[0,1]$ and $\epsilon=\frac{1}{2}$. Does this work or have I made a mistake?

Comment: @anon I asked for geodesic space, and snowflake is not geodesic. But it is a nice observation.

Comment: Of course, I missed the request that the space be geodesic! It is an interesting question.